# How to create an instance of <T> with arguments in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, templating

I have a generic class and need to create an instance of  with some arguments. I found how to create an instance with an empty constructor, but when I try overload it I get an error: 'ERROR TypeError: rowObj is not a constructor'

Here is the old code that works (but with empty constructor):

```
export class DataTableViewModel<TRow extends DataTableRowViewModel> {
public rowsViewModel: TRow[];
public totalItemsCount: number;

constructor(dateService: DateService, rows?: any[]) {
    this.rowsViewModel = [];
    if (rows) {
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            let obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.create(row) as TRow);
            this.rowsViewModel.push(obj);
        });
    }
}
}
```

Here is the new code I am trying to make work:

```
export abstract class DataTableViewModel<TRow extends DataTableRowViewModel> {
public rowsViewModel: TRow[];
public totalItemsCount: number;

constructor(dateService: DateService, rows?: { new(): any }[]) {
    this.rowsViewModel = [];
    if (rows) {
        let rowObj: { new(dateService: DateService, rows?: any): TRow };
        rows.forEach((row) => {
            let obj = new rowObj(dateService, row);
            this.rowsViewModel.push(obj);
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is a `DataTableRowViewModel` and what is the signature of its constructor?

Comment: @jcalz it's just an empty class for now, without any declared constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared a variable `rowObj` but you haven't initialised it. You will need to assign a constructor to it, and you'll have to arrange to get that constructor from somewhere.

You cannot just create a `TRow` object: that name exists only in the compile-time type space, it doesn't exist at runtime. Somewhere you will have to have a concrete object you can call. For example you might add it as another parameter to the constructor:

```
export abstract class DataTableViewModel<TRow extends DataTableRowViewModel> {
    public rowsViewModel: TRow[];
    public totalItemsCount: number;

    constructor(rowObj: { new(dateService: DateService, rows?: any): TRow },
     dateService: DateService, rows?: { new(): any }[]) {
        this.rowsViewModel = [];
        if (rows) {
            rows.forEach((row) => {
                let obj = new rowObj(dateService, row);
                this.rowsViewModel.push(obj);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to use it after? What should be passed as a first argument?

Comment: You need to pass in some concrete class that implements your abstract class.